# Proof of modulo property

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

There is a video on youtube where a guy in the comments proves the following:

If $15l \equiv 2 \mod7$, then $l \equiv 2 \mod7$.

He does it like this:

> 15L = 2 (mod 7)
>
> => 15L = 7k + 2 for some k in the integers
>
> Let k = 2T where T is an integer
>
> => 15L = 14T + 2
>
> => L = 14T - 14L + 2
>
> => L = 7(2T - 2L) + 2
>
> Let H = (2T - 2L), then H is an integer.
>
> => L = 7H + 2
>
> => L = 2 (mod 7)

What bothers me is the following line "Let k = 2T where T is an integer". Why replace $k$ with a multiple of 2? We would get the same result if we do not even replace $k$ and leave it as it is for example:

L = 7k - 14L + 2

=> L = 7(k - 2L) + 2

=> L = 2 (mod 7)

Is my method correct as well or is there some deeper reasoning as to why would he replace $k$ with $2T$?

**EDIT**: 
Here is the video if anyone is interested, the comment is made by the user **RB**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LInNgWMtFEs&lc=z23ts1qyloeagpzhm04t1aokgn15f4y4gqsns5m1d5p3rk0h00410.1543158282809495

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you are right and the video is wrong.  For instance, we could have $k=19$, which can't be written as $k=2T$ for an integer $T$.

By the way, a possibly simpler approach to the whole thing is to note that $15\equiv 1 \pmod{7}$.

So $2\equiv 15l\equiv l \pmod{7}$.

Answer (score 4):

Your concerns about the video are justified.

E.g. we have $15\times 9=135=7\times 19+2$ but there is no integer $k$ such that $15\times 9=135=14k+2$.

Your method is okay.

On base of $7\mid 14l$ you can also observe that: $$7\mid 15l-2\iff7\mid 14l+l-2\iff 7\mid l-2$$

Comment: I am not sure what does your last sentence prove. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think the last part should be $7 | l - 2$

Comment: @MichaelMunta Indeed that was a typo. Repaired now. Thank you for attending me. Is everything clear to you now?

Comment: No problem. I am just not sure how $14l$ disappears from $7|14l + l - 2$. Can you explain?

Comment: $7\mid a$ together with $7\mid b$ implies that $7|a-b$. That can be applied on $a=14l+l-2$ and $b=14l$.

Answer (score 3):

The argument is incorrect since $\, 15\,l = 7\,k+2\,$ does not imply $\,2\mid k\,\,$ (e.g. $\ l,k  = -5,-11$). Further, the argument uses unidirectional inferences where bidirectional inferences are required. Below is one correct way to do the proof in that manner.

$$\begin{align}
15\, l &\equiv 2\!\pmod{\! 7}\\ 
\iff \exists\, k\!:\ 15\,l &= 2+7\,k\\
\iff \exists\, k\!:\ \ \ \ \ \ l &= 2+7(k\!-\!2l)\\
\iff \exists\, j\!:\ \ \ \ \ \ l &= 2+7\,j\\
\iff\qquad\quad\ \, l &\equiv 2\!\pmod{\! 7}
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

It's simpler to use basic rules of modular arithmetic. By the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) we deduce

$\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{15\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{15}\,l\equiv \color{#c00}1\,l\equiv l\ $ thus $\ 2\equiv 15\,l\equiv l$

Answer (score 2):

If someone in their comments indeed says that, then your doubts are well justified — that step is plain wrong. In the setting of this question, $k$ does **NOT** have to be an even number, so we can **NOT** (in general) set it to be $2t$ for an integer $t$.

Quick example: if $l=9$, then $15l=15\cdot9=135\equiv2 \mod7$, but then $k=133/7=19$ can't be represented as "$k=2t$ for an integer $t$".

Your solution, however, is perfectly correct!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using

- $\color{blue}{15 \equiv 1 \mod 7}$?
  $$\Rightarrow \color{blue}{15}l \equiv \color{blue}{1}l \equiv 2 \mod 7$$